# Another implication of the Affine Desargues Axiom

Tags: lo.logic, euclidean-geometry, affine-geometry, incidence-geometry

**Definition 1.** An *affine plane* is a pair $(X,\mathcal L)$ consisting of a set $X$ and a family $\mathcal L$ of subsets of $X$ called *lines* which satisfy the following axioms:

1. Any distinct points $x,y\in X$ are contained in a unique line $L\in\mathcal L$;
2. Any line $L\in \mathcal L$ contains at least three points;
3. $X\notin \mathcal L$;
4. For every line $L\in\mathcal L$ and point $x\in X\setminus L$ there exists a unique line $\Lambda\in\mathcal L$ such that $x\in \Lambda$ and $\Lambda\cap L=\emptyset$.

For two distinct points $x,y\in X$ of an affine space $(X,\mathcal L)$ by $\overline{xy}$ we denote the unique line containing the points $x,y$.

Two lines $A,B\in\mathcal L$ are called *parallel* (denoted by $A\parallel B$ ) if either $A=B$ or $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

**Definition 2.** An affine plane $(X,\mathcal L)$ is called *Desarguesian* if it satisfies the *Affine Desargues Axiom*: for every lines $A,B,C\in\mathcal L$ with $A\cap B\cap C\ne\emptyset$ and any points $a,a'\in A\setminus(B\cup C)$, $b,b'\in B\setminus(A\cup C)$, $c,c'\in C\setminus(A\cup B)$, if $\overline{ab}\parallel \overline{a'b'}$ and $\overline{bc}\parallel \overline{b'c'}$, then $\overline{ac}\parallel \overline{a'c'}$.

> **Problem.** Let $o,a,b,c,x,y,z,p$ be eight distinct points in a Desarguesian affine plane $(X,\mathcal L)$ such that the lines $\overline{oc}$ and $\overline{oz}$ are distinct,  $a,b\in \overline{oc}$ and $x,y\in\overline{oz}$, $\overline{xp}{\parallel} \overline{oc}$, $\overline{ap}{\parallel} \overline{oz}$, $\overline{xa}{\parallel} \overline{yb}$, $\overline{xb}{\parallel} \overline{pc}$, and $\overline{ay}{\parallel}\overline{pz}$.
> Is $\overline{zc}\parallel \overline{yb}$?

[image]

**Remark 1.** I hope that the answer is affirmative. In this case, it would be desirable to have a direct proof from the axioms, which does not use the algebraization of Desarguesian affine planes  (because I need this fact to introduce the operation of addition of scalars).

**Remark 2.** @AlexRavsky observed that in order to solve Problem 1 affirmatively, it suffices to prove that the lines $\overline{ay}$, $\overline{bx}$ and $\overline{op}$ have a common point $q$.
Unfortunately, this is not always true (at least without the additional information provided by the points $c$ and $z$) as shown in the following picture.

[image]

In this case, however $c=z=o$, which contradicts the choice of the points $c$ and $z$. So, maybe in case $c\ne o\ne z$, the point $q\in\overline{op}\cap\overline{ay}\cap\overline{bx}$ indeed exists.

Comment: Ignoring degenerated cases, the picture suggests to put $q$ as the intersection point of $\overline{ay}$ and $\overline{bx}$. If $q$ belongs to $\overline{op}$ then it should be  $\overline{zc}\parallel \overline{yb}$ by the Affine Desargues Axiom.
Next, I hope that $q$ belongs to $\overline{op}$ by some kind of an inverse of 
Affine Desargues Axiom because $\overline{aq}=\overline{qy}$,
$\overline{bq}=\overline{qx}$, and $\overline{xa}=\overline{yb}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky I also thought about this point $q$.  One should first prove that it indeed exists. In fact, one can find a configuration of the eight points where $aybx$ is a parallelogram and $o$ is the intersection of its diagonals. In this case the point $q$ does not exist.  By the way, the line $\overline{xa}$ is parallel (but not equal) to $\overline{yb}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky A drawing in which $aybx$ is a parallelogram yields tha $c=o$, so maybe the point $q$ indeed exists.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Sasha, you are right! The solution consists in two steps: first, we prove that the point $q$ exists (because otherwise $c=o$) and then apply the Affine Desargues Axiom (and its inversion) to prove that $\overline{zc}\parallel \overline{yb}$.  If you will write down this solution, I will accept it and will close this question as solved.

Comment: @AlexRavsky The existence of the point $q$ can be proved as follows: we define $q$ as the intersection of the lines $\overline{op}$ and $\overline{bx}$. The intersection exists by the Proclus Axiom, which holds in affine planes. Then we apply the Affine Desargues Axiom to prove that the line $\overline{qy}$ is parallel to $\overline{zp}$ and hence $\overline{qy}=\overline{ay}$. Finally, apply the Affine Desargues Axiom to show that $\overline{zc}\parallel \overline{yb}$.

Comment: @AlexRavsky The problem with this point $q$ is not so simple (the argument from my preceding comment does not work). So, another argument should be invented as to why the point $q$ exists and belongs to the line $\overline{op}$.

Comment: "Since the lines $\overline{oc}$ and $\overline{oz}$ are distinct, the lines the lines $\overline{op}$ and $\overline{bx}$ are distinct too. The lines $\overline{op}$ and $\overline{bx}$ intersect. Indeed, otherwise the line $\overline{op}$ coincides with the unique line containing $p$ and parallel to $\overline{bx}$, which is $\overline{pc}$. Then $p\in\overline{oc}$. Since $\overline{xp}$ is parallel to $\overline{oc}$, $x\in\overline{oc}$, and then the lines $\overline{oc}$ and $\overline{oz}$ coincide, a contradiction".

Comment: @AlexRavsky The existence of $q$ (as the intersection of $\overline{op}$ and $\overline{bx}$) indeed can be proved (as you did or by Proclus Axiom). The question is why this $q$ belongs to the line $\overline{ay}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question as answered, I will give a sketch of the proof of the parallelity of the lines $\overline{zc}$ and $\overline{yb}$.

As was noticed by @AlexRavsky, it suffices to prove that the lines $\overline{ay}$, $\overline{bx}$ and $\overline{op}$ have a common point $q$. Then we can apply the Affine Desargues Axiom to the triangles $pzc$ and $qyb$ and conclude that $\overline{zc}\parallel \overline{yb}$.

To prove that a point $q\in \overline{ay}\cap\overline{bx}\cap \overline{op}$ exists, we first prove that the lines $\overline{ay}$ and $\overline{bx}$ have a common point. In the opposite case the lines $\overline{ay}$ and $\overline{bx}$ are parallel and the quadruple $aybx$ is a parallelogram whose diagonals $\overline{ab}$ and $\overline{xy}$ intersect at the point $o$.

Since $oxpa$ is a parallelogram and $\overline{pc}\parallel \overline{xb}\parallel\overline{ay}$ the point $c$ coincides with the point $o$, which contradicts the choice of the (distinct) points $o,a,b,c,x,y,z$. This contradiction shows that the lines $\overline{ay}$ and $\overline{bx}$ have a common point $q$.

Using the Playfair Axiom, find a point $q'$ such $\overline{aq'}\parallel \overline{qa}$ and $\overline{xq'}\parallel \overline{qx}$. So that $q'aqx$ is a parallelogram. Using the Inverse Desargues Theorem (that follows from the Affine Desargues Axiom), it can be shown that the point $q'$ belongs to the line $\overline{oq}$.

It is known that the Affine Desargues Axiom implies its "parallel'' version (in which the lines $A,B,C$ are parallel). In affine planes satisfying this weaker "parallel'' version of the Affine Desargues Axiom, the notion of a vector (as an equivalence class of pairs of points) can be introduced. Moreover, we can define the operation of addition of vectors and show that it is associative and commutative.

Taking into account that $oapx$ and $q'aqx$ are parallelograms, we can see that
$$\overrightarrow{pq}=\overrightarrow{qx}+\overrightarrow{xp}=\overrightarrow{aq'}+\overrightarrow{oa}=\overrightarrow{oa}+\overrightarrow{aq'}=\overrightarrow{oq'}$$
and hence the point $p$ belongs to the line $\overline{oq}$.

Therefore, the answer to the original question is affirmative but the proof is a bit complicated (in fact, we can fulfil the last step without vectors, just using the "parallel" Affine Desargues Theorem, but in this case more lines and triangles should be drawn).